# Is there any function to plot similar to geom_smooth() in Plotly using python?

Tags: python, plotly

I have made a scatterplot using Plotly (python), and i want to connect the dots using something similar to geom_smooth() function.

Something like below image :
[image]

Comment: Does setting `mode='lines+markers'` do the job?

Comment: @NickilMaveli : no, that gives straight lines. I was wondering if we can have smooth lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it by setting the shape='spline' when defining the line. here is the plotly example

```
trace2 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[6, 8, 7, 8, 6],
    mode='lines+markers',
    name="'spline'",
    text=["tweak line smoothness<br>with 'smoothing' in line object"],
    hoverinfo='text+name',
    line=dict(
        shape='spline'
    )
)
```

See an example here: [plotly line charts](https://plot.ly/python/line-charts/)